# Nasm Hello World Bus Error OS X

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm

I have the following assembly code (copied from [here](http://thebrownnotebook.wordpress.com/2009/10/27/native-64-bit-hello-world-with-nasm-on-freebsd/)):

`hello.asm`:

```
section .data
    msg: db  'hello, world!', 0

section .text

global _start
_start:
    mov     rax, 4
    mov     rdi, 1
    mov     rsi, qword msg ; I added qword because the compiler complained
    mov     rdx, 13
    syscall

    mov     rax, 1
    xor     rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

As explained in the comment above I added `qword` because I recieved the following error message:

```
$ yasm -f macho64 hello.asm
hello.asm:10: error: macho: sorry, cannot apply 32 bit absolute relocations in 64 bit mode, consider "[_symbol wrt rip]" for mem access, "qword" and "dq _foo" for pointers.
```

After making that change, both compiling and linking succeed, but I get a bus error while running:

```
$ yasm -f macho64 hello.asm
$ ld -o hello -e _start hello.o
$ ./hello
bus error  ./hello
```

Is the addition of `qword` incorrect, or is there something else I need to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

64-bit system calls on OSX need to have a class specifier in bits 24..31 of the register that holds the system call number (`rax` in your case). You've implicitly used the class specifier 0, [which is invalid](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.26.8/osfmk/mach/i386/syscall_sw.h).

You probably want the UNIX/BSD class, which means that you should be adding `2<<24` (`0x2000000`). So these lines:

```
mov     rax, 4
mov     rax, 1
```

should be changed to:

```
mov     rax, 0x2000004
mov     rax, 0x2000001
```

Also, I don't see what purpose that `sub rsp, 8` at the end is serving, so you can probably remove that line.

Comment: The "sub rsp, 8" instruction may also cause problems: In Windows many system instructions cause a crash if the stack is not aligned to 16 bytes.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Sorry, the `sub rsp, 8` was mistakenly left there from one of my attempts to fix the problem. Interestingly the program compiles and runs with and without the instruction.